# Replace bad characters in python

Tags: replace

Please help, the print (line) will return Hello$ Python#. It should be "Hello Python"

```
line = "Hello$ Python#"

for char in line:
    if char in "$#":
        line.replace(char,'')

print (line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with what your doing is: You are altering the string `line` in a loop using the `replace` method without assigning it to anything. You should create a new variable to store the new string.

Try this:

```
line = "Hello$ Python#"
return_line = ""
for char in line:
  if char not in "$#":
    return_line += char

print(return_line)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! You also gave me another idea that I could also do just assign the line name to my original code.                                                                                                    
 `line = "Hello$ Python#"

for char in line:
    if char in "$#":
        line = line.replace(char,'')

print (line)`

Comment: thanks, if it works can you please upvote my answer, and also accept it. Thanks !